# Hardware for Low-Latency transmission from Microcontroller to PC

Tags: real-time, microcontroller, sensors, latency

First and foremost I aware of a "similar" question/answer here: [USB: low latency (< 1ms) with interrupt transfer and raw HID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27976992/usb-low-latency-1ms-with-interrupt-transfer-and-raw-hid)

In my case I'm at the start of my project and currently choosing the "right hardware" for the job. I want to transfer raw sensor data from an IMU to a host PC in roughly <1ms. So my Idea was to use a Teensy or Arduino uC to handle the interface between IMU and PC. The current priority is driving the input latency down as best as possible using (ideally) the USB protocol. I'm well aware that once on the PC I have to deal with a non real-time system.

Is there anything "hardware-wise" that I have to pay attention when choosing my Microcontroller?

Comment: there are going to be latencies on the MCU side as well.  getting the data in from the sensor, the software involved in handling the interrupt and or moving/prepping the data, then dealing with the usb stack.  The software libraries I assume you are hoping to use may have bloat in the software to make it easier to use or for them to program, that may cause extra time as well.  You may wish to just grab a handful of different boards and test them.  You probably want something on the order of a cortex-m (or mips) vs an avr or pic

Comment: What you could look for is an MCU that does the usb stack for you in hardware where you just need to fill in a buffer to have the data picked up...